# How to reject a project that does not fit with my skills or goes beyond my skills in order to keep your client for future projects?

Tags: attracting-clients, communication, programmer, client-support, project-bidding

I am having problems with how to reject this kind of project for my clients. As an example, a recent client that weeks ago I did a C Project for him arrives again days ago needing help in a project related to parallel computing and multi-threading. I had to refuse because this topic is outside my skills. Another example can be if I have a client that comes to me needing help with NLP (Natural Language Processing) and I know more of Computer Vision, Python, scikit-learn, etc.

If the project is easy, I could help, but if do not I don't know how to answer without being "rude", ghost him/her or look unprofessional. **clients judge a lot** (Mostly clients who I had to reject him/her do not return offering more work. On the other hand, those who I have worked with have stayed with me and have even offered me projects out of the skills of the first project).

> If we are sincere from the perspective of a client if you cannot solve
> his project it is because you have a lack of experience in the area (
> when I said area I am meaning all the skills not only the specific
> skill that we can't do it) and He will look for a better freelancer
> than if he knows his technologies and will keep him with him for
> future projects.

- **What do I have to do in case a client or potential client offers me a job outside of my skills and how to retain them for future offers?**
- **What is the best answer in this case for retaining your client for future projects?**

I think a good idea is to list my skills in order to give the client an idea of my skills.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to keep that client is to find a subcontractor who can do the job. In that way, you move from being "a programmer" to "someone who solves computer problems." When you have a client who is willing to spend money on you, take the money and find someone who can do the work they need.

Edit:
Make sure that you price the subcontractor work high enough. You will be doing a lot of management work that needs to be compensated. Typical markup can be 2-3 times the subcontractor price.